# É possível ter conteúdo(layouts, classes) nativo em uma aplicação hibrida?

Tags: android, ionic, android-activity, app-hibrido

Necessito executar alguns layouts e classes nativas do Android no meu projeto Ionic existe algum plugin?

Comment: Poderia descrever melhor o que você quer fazer? Que layouts e classes nativas são essas? Como está o seu projeto Ionic?

Comment: Pergunta reaberta, pode postar sua resposta. Mas a pergunta provavelmente precisa ser editada também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível e não é difícil fazer com o meu projeto para **Android** fiz de uma forma muito simples sem a necessidade de um **plugin**. O que fiz eu criei o meu **AppWidget** em **Android Studio** modificado da maneira que eu queria. Fui ao meu projeto **Ionic, gerei a plataforma Android**, então copiei os **classes java** e **layouts .xml** depois em **platform / android**.

> Adaptei de acordo com a minha necessidade no meu caso
>   **res/xml, res/layouts, res/drawable** e em pastas
>   **src/seu_pacote** depois que eu só precisava acertar meu AndroidManisfest.